# How can I create a table with two categories and then sort by one of them in R?

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a full dataset of observations and over 40 columns of categories but I only want two, NameID and Error and I want to sort Error in a descending order but still have NameID connected to each observation. Here is some code I've tried:

```
        z<-15
        sort(data.frame(skill$Error,skill$NameID),decreasing = TRUE)[1:z]
        data.frame(skill$NameID,sort(kill@Error,decreasing=T)[1:z])
        error2<-skill[order(Error , )]
```

Hopefully from what I've tried you can understand what I'm trying to do. Again, I want to pull two values from my skills data set, Error and NameID, but have Error sorted at the same time with NameID attached to the values. I need this all done inside of R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(Error=skill$Error,NameID=skill$NameID)
df <- df[order(df$Error, decreasing=TRUE), ]
```

best of luck with whatever you are doing.  Hopefully you have someone else to learn some R from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `skill` is a data frame

```
Errors <- skill[,c("Error","NameID")]
Errors <- Errors[order(-Errors$Error),]
```

You don't want to ever use sort in a data frame because it sorts whatever column you tell it to independently from the rest of the data frame. You only ever want order, order keeps the links between other columns intact.

Comment: To be more specific, `order()` in this case returns the index of column numbers corresponding to the sorted values of `Error`, where as `sort()` just returns the sorted values of `Error`.

Comment: Awesome, you da best.